# Скрытие не поместившегося текста в UILabel слева

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Возможно ли сделать скрытие не поместившегося текста ("...") на UILabel не справа, как обычно, а слева? Отображая тем самым не начало строки, а ее конец.

Вот скриншот, как это выглядит сейчас:
[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead;
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.